# python. работа с несколькими сокетами одновременно

Tags: python, сокет

день добрый!
есть программа которая слушает сокет.
 1. как сделать, чтобы можно было одновременно создавать несколько сокетов и работать с ними. т.к. при создании одного сокета, программа работает только с ним.
 2. как сильно увеличится время отклика на каждом из сокетов. предполагается работать одновременно с 7 сокетами.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
__author__ = 'p.olifer'

'''
server socket
listening only 1 port at time

create date : 2019-01-09
author      : p.olifer
version     : 4.0
'''

import socket, datetime
import work_with_DB, logging
from goto import with_goto
import conf

class socket_server():
    def __init__(self, ip, port):
        self.ip = ip
        self.port = port
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.sock.bind((self.ip, self.port))
        self.sock.listen(5)

    @with_goto
    def run(self):
        label .begin
        self.conn, self.addr = self.sock.accept()
        self.conn.setblocking(1)

        while True:
            try:
                self.query_from_MES = self.conn.recv(10000).strip()

                if not len(self.query_from_MES) == 0:
                    flag = self.query_from_MES[0:3]

                    if flag == 'REQ':
                        answer = self.query_from_MES + work_with_DB.get_last_receiving_data(self.port)
                        self.conn.send(answer)
                    else:
                        answer = work_with_DB.upload_data(self.query_from_MES[0:4000], self.port)
                        return_msg = self.query_from_MES[0:45] + answer

                        self.conn.send(return_msg)

                        if answer[0:2] == conf._SEND_ERROR:                    
                            self.conn.close()
                            try:
                                s1 = socket_server(self.ip, self.port)
                                s1.run()
                            except Exception as e:
                                # returns the name of the exception
                                pass
                else:
                    goto.begin
            except socket.error, e:
                if e.errno == 10054:
                    goto.begin  

import conf
#import socket_server_ver3 as socket_server
import socket_server_ver4 as socket_server

if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = socket_server.socket_server(conf._IP, conf._PORT_9217)
    s.run()
```

Comment: По идее несколько сокетов - это несколько потоков. Или вы хотите на одном потоке слушать несколько сокетов? Если так, то скорее всего это не получится у вас.

Comment: `from goto import with_goto` о, а это что за прелесть?

Comment: это использовать go to - переход к метке в любом месте текста.
когда только начал писать программу, думал без этого никак, сейчас не уверен, что она нужна, но программа вот уже год работает без сбоев - не убираю.

Comment: я не знаю как лучше сделать.
сейчас, чтобы запустить программу для прослушивания 7 сокетов, я создал 7 файлов. и эти файлы закрепил за сервисами (службами), чтобы скрипты работали как процесс на виндовом сервере. может быть есть вариант - использование потока, тогда создать 1 файл и в нем запускать прослушивание 7 сокетов.

Comment: @polly_, добавляйте `@<ник>`, а то не придет уведомление адресату :) Для этого вы можете создавать потоки или процессы с функциями с сокетами прямо в коде, пример: [1](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/079b6d5285c3a728ab22d9e5a658e6dad32d0a51/multithreading__threading__examples/threading_with_webservers__flask.py), [2](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/079b6d5285c3a728ab22d9e5a658e6dad32d0a51/multiprocessing__examples/multiprocessing_with_webservers__flask.py) . Эти ссылки введу к файлам, а в их можно еще примеры найти

Comment: @gil9red спасибо!)

Comment: @gil9red сделал отдельную функцию, которую вызываю. и по итогу получаю ошибку - ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Answer (score 2):

Для удобства добавляете функцию-обертку с двумя параметрами:

```
def run(ip, port):
    s = socket_server.socket_server(conf._IP, conf._PORT_9217)
    s.run()
```

И ее запускаете в потоке ([threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html)):

```
from threading import Thread

for port in [5000, 5001, 5002]:
    thread = Thread(target=run, args=('localhost', port,))
    thread.start()
```

Код для запуска в процессе ([multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html)) аналогичный, но обязательно его оформляйте в `if __name__ == '__main__':`

```
from multiprocessing import Process

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for port in [5000, 5001, 5002]:
        p = Process(target=run, args=('localhost', port,))
        p.start()
```

`args` передаст в параметры `run` указанные значения

---

**PS.**

В `Thread` и `Process` желательно передавать параметр `daemon=False`, который не даст завершиться родительскому процессу пока выполняется поток/процесс с таким флагом.

По умолчанию, в них передается `daemon=None`. В таком случае значение будет определено из значения `daemon` у родителя (думаю, для обычно запускаемых скриптов это `False`).

Сделал пару примеров:

- Для потоков когда: [daemon=True](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/dee38a960d0561ce0d284237647848fc567b6250/multithreading__threading__examples/hello_world__with_daemon.py) и [daemon=False](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/dee38a960d0561ce0d284237647848fc567b6250/multithreading__threading__examples/hello_world__without_daemon.py)
- Для процессов когда: [daemon=True](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/514e86310057a56116b38ecc5a0338f52e5be898/multiprocessing__examples/hello_world__with_daemon.py) и [daemon=False](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/203ef3f82f9c814e2a8a5642882ac8a32a7c8441/multiprocessing__examples/hello_world__without_daemon.py)

**PPS.**

Еще интересной вещью может быть - `Pool`:

- Для процессов: `from multiprocessing import Pool`
- Для потоков: `from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool` ([такой же интерфейс как для процессов](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.dummy))

`Pool` позволит упростить код запуска одного потока/процесса на указанную коллекцию с сбором результат выполнения:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
    return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(5) as p:
        print(p.map(f, [1, 2, 3]))
```

Comment: подскажите, по нагрузке на процессор и использование ресурсов, какой вариант самый оптимальный?

Comment: @polly_ потоки, думаю будут не так тяжеловесны, в отличии от процессов, поэтому вариант с `Thread`

Comment: сделал отдельную функцию, которую вызываю. и по итогу получаю ошибку - ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Comment: @polly_, думал вы уже и не ответите :D скорее всего, указанный порт уже занят другим сокетом или с той стороны по указанному порту никто не слушает

Comment: так что самое интересное, программа запущена, пишет, что слушает, но по итогу вылетает ошибка

Comment: только что запустил в старой версии программу - с ошибкой не вылетело.

Comment: разобрался. вместо ip подавал 'localhost'